# ASP.NET MVC Social Login's are working in Local but after deploying into Azure getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

Hi am new for MVC I am using Social logins for my testing site while testing in Localhost it's working but after deploying into Azure getting an error please look at below screenshot and help me, someone, to overcome this.

**Error is:** **An error occurred while processing your request**

Please check the code I used this code in Startup.auth.us

```
  //Facebook
        var facebook = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = "xxxxxx",
            AppSecret = "xxx",              
        };
        facebook.Scope.Add("email");
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebook);

        //Google
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "xxxxx",
            ClientSecret = "xxxx"
        });

         //Linkedin
        app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(
            clientId: "xxxxx",
            clientSecret: "xxxxxx"

            );

        //Instagram
        app.UseInstagramInAuthentication(
            clientId: "xxxxx",
            clientSecret: "xxxxx"
            );
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I tried logging in using `LinkedIn` and I was told that redirect URI does not match. Have you configured the redirect URI properly with Facebook etc.?

Comment: Ya Gaurav, here is the Redirect URL I used and not only for facebook all the social logins are getting same issue https://atstest.azurewebsites.net/signin-facebook

Comment: I was able to login using Facebook. Did not get any error messages.

Comment: please check with connection string

Comment: Hi Gaurav, after logging into facebook its returning Null that means login info not getting from FB Look at URL https://atstest.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login#_=_ this is not exact url after logging into facebook. If the login was successful it will displays Email id in Header but still its showing register

Comment: That's what I also noticed. But I did not get the error you included in the question.

Comment: Hi TAHA SULTAN TEMURI,
i think Connection string is not necessary for logins why because am not using database

Comment: Can you please give me this project f . Thanks. Im waiting Upload somewhere share link if possible.

Comment: Hi Asif, check with below url for code
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A0SUdevcxj2_ToHu4Hg5PLSbVvAosZqb

Comment: Thanks , Happy coding

Comment: Hi Asif, Did you find the resolution??